# Flutter padding for all widgets?

Tags: android, ios, flutter

I'm trying to add some padding to the top and bottom of some text and icons in a Card widget. I found that flutter has an easy way to do this for containers, but can't seem to find a way to do this with other widgets (except for wrapping them in a container). This is the code I've got so far:

```
  body: new Container(
    padding: new EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
    child: new Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
      children: <Widget> [
        new Card(
          color: Colors.white70,
          child: new Container(
            padding: new EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
            child: new Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget> [ //Padding between these please
                new Text("I love Flutter", style: new TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                new Icon(Icons.favorite, color: Colors.redAccent, size: 50.0)
              ]
            )
          )
        )
      ]
    )
  )
```

So in my children of column, I'd like to add some padding to the top and bottom without having to insert a new Container. Is this possible?

Comment: [Flutter Padding: Ultimate Guilde](https://androidride.com/flutter-padding-widget/)

Answer (score 106, accepted):

You can use `Padding`, which is a very simple `Widget` that just takes another `Widget` as a `child` and an `EdgeInsets` object like the one you are already using as `padding`.

This approach of "composition over inheritance" in Flutter is very intentional. You can find a recent discussion of the pros and cons on Flutter's [Gitter channel](https://gitter.im/flutter/flutter?at=58ff58a908c00c092ab41dc9).

Comment: This worked perfectly. I just stumbled upon the docs for this and it stated that using a Container or Padding doesn't really make a difference. It just appears more readable to me to use padding for a widget without children like Text or Icon! Thanks :)

Comment: In that case, why container widget has padding :) ?

Answer (score 89):

Here is a supplemental answer that provides some code. As the accepted answer states, you can use the Padding widget. Flutter is different than Android or iOS because Padding is a widget rather than a property. (It is a property of Container, but internally it is still a widget.)

This is a Text widget wrapped with a Padding widget.

```
Padding(
  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
  child: Text("text"),
);
```

See my fuller answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53679108/3681880).

Comment: does that apply padding to each child item or all together?

Comment: @jonney, Padding only takes one child. If the child has a child, though, the padding will only be added around the Padding widget's direct child.

Comment: Putting the `Padding` object into `children: <Widget>[` array made it work.

Answer (score 15):

If you are using Visual Studio Code, highlight your widget, click on the lightbulb, and select Wrap with Padding from the menu.

[image]

As you can see in the picture, it automatically wrapped the widget around a Padding widget.

[image]

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Container(child: Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
      child: TextField(
        decoration: InputDecoration(border: InputBorder.none, hintText: 'Enter a text'),
      ),
    ));
  }
```

Answer (score 9):

[image: Flutter Padding]

[More information - Flutter Padding](https://androidride.com/flutter-padding-widget/)

Use Padding Widget.

Below code just add padding to Text Widget like shown in the image. Use Flutter Inspector to see how padding laid out.

```
Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(50.0),
          child: Text('Text Widget'),
        ),
```