# How to set margin for a Button in Flutter

Tags: button, flutter, margin, flutter-layout

I am just creating a form in Flutter. I am not able to set the top margin for the button.

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {

String firstname; 
String lastname;
final scaffoldKey = new GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();
final formKey = new GlobalKey<FormState>();


    @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      key: scaffoldKey,
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Text('Validating forms'),
      ),
      body: new Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
        child: new Form(
          key: formKey,
          child: new Column(
            children: [
              new TextFormField(
                decoration: new InputDecoration(labelText: 'First Name'),
                validator: (val) =>
                    val.length == 0 ?"Enter FirstName" : null,
                onSaved: (val) => firstname = val,
              ),
              new TextFormField(
                decoration: new InputDecoration(labelText: 'Password'),
                validator: (val) =>
                    val.length ==0 ? 'Enter LastName' : null,
                onSaved: (val) => lastname = val,
                obscureText: true,
              ),
              new RaisedButton(
                onPressed: _submit,
                child: new Text('Login'),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 137, accepted):

Put your button inside a [Container](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/Container-class.html) and then set the margin

```dart
Container(
    margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 10.0),
    child : RaisedButton(
        onPressed: _submit,
        child: Text('Login'),
     ),
)
```

Answer (score 47):

Alternatively you can wrap your button with Padding. (That is what Container does internally.)

```
Padding(
  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
  child: ElevatedButton(
    onPressed: _submit,
    child: Text('Login'),
  ),
);
```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53679108/3681880) more more on adding margin to a widget.

**Note**: `RaisedButton` is deprecated as of Flutter 2.0. `ElevatedButton` is the replacement.

Comment: This should be accepted answer, because Padding can be marked as const, whereas Container cannot.

Comment: @AdamSmaka Out of curiosity - what is the advantage of sth being marked as const?

Comment: @Diana the value is build only once so the performance of an app is better

Answer (score 7):

In Flutter 2.0, RaisedButton was deprecated, The ElevatedButton is replacement.
So you can use ElevatedButton and set style as bellow to remove margin:

```
      ElevatedButton.icon(
        onPressed: () {},
        icon: Icon(Icons.add),
        label: Text(
          'Add Place',
        ),
        style: ButtonStyle(tapTargetSize: MaterialTapTargetSize.shrinkWrap),
      ),
```

Answer (score 2):

**image marging top:**

```
        Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Color.fromARGB(255, 238, 237, 237),
      body: Center(
        child: Container(
          margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 25),
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Column(children: <Widget>[
                Image.asset(
                  'images/logo.png',
                  fit: BoxFit.contain,
                  width: 130,
                )
              ]),
              
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    )
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the EdgeInsets.symmetric:

```
child : new RaisedButton(
   onPressed: _submit,
   child: new Text('Login'),
   padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 50, vertical: 10),
),
```

Answer (score 1):

**Screenshot:**

[image]

Use the recommended **`ElevatedButton.style`** property to provide padding.

```dart
ElevatedButton(
  onPressed: () {},
  child: Text('Button'),
  style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
    padding: EdgeInsets.all(20), // Set padding
  ),
)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how I set the size, padding, and margin of widgets in general. here is an example for Button:

```
   Container(
          margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10), // Top Margin
          child:
            ElevatedButton(
              style: TextButton.styleFrom(

                // Inside Padding 
                padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 0, vertical: 20), 

                // Width,Height
                minimumSize: Size(300, 30), 
              ),
              child: Text('Upload Data'),
              onPressed: () {submitForm();},
            ),
        ),
```

Other Options are

```
Container(
          margin: EdgeInsets.only(top:20),
          child:
            ElevatedButton(
```

[image]

set horizontal & vertical margins

```
Container(
margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 0, vertical: 20),
child:
```

[image]

```
Container(
          margin: EdgeInsets.all(20),
          child:
            ElevatedButton(
```

[image]

```
Container(
          margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(5,10,5,10),
          child:
            ElevatedButton(
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is worked for me!

```
ElevatedButton(
   style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
     primary: Global.deepOrange,
     padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20), // at this line you can add margin.
              ),
  onPressed: () {},
    child: const Text('Add New Poll Item')),
```

Answer (score 0):

```
child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: <Widget>[
              Text(data.dataList[index].codeName, style: TextStyle(fontSize: 14, fontWeight: FontWeight.w500, color: UtilColors.darkGrey)),
              Row(
                //TODO to edit employee details
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Expanded(child: Text(BasicAction.formatDate(data.dataList[index].payDate), style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16, fontWeight: FontWeight.w500, color: UtilColors.darkGrey))),
                  Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(4),
                    child: Text('Edit', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 14, fontWeight: FontWeight.w500, color: UtilColors.blueColor)),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ],
          ),

in this on edit text how to set clicklistenr
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **margin** and **padding** on **Card** like this:-

```
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: ListView.builder(
          itemCount: _newsArticles.length,
          padding:  EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 2,vertical: 2),
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            return Card( // <-- Card widget
              shadowColor: Colors.grey,
              elevation: 3,
              margin: EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
              child: ListTile(
                title: _newsArticles[index].urlToImage == null ?
                Image.asset(Constants.NEWS_PLACEHOLDER_IMAGE_ASSET_URL) :
                Image.network(_newsArticles[index].urlToImage),
                subtitle: Text(_newsArticles[index].title, style: TextStyle(fontSize: 14)),
              ),
            );
          },
        )
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Margin and Padding are not the same thing and I feel like they are being used interchangeably in some of the comments.

Margin controls the spacing from outside of the widget border to its edge.
Padding controls the spacing from its edge, to its child.

For the ElevatedButton widget, [trung's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5650873/trung-%C4%90oan) answer is correct, change the tapTargetSize in the button style.

Comment: This was meant to be a comment, not another answer, apologies.