# So I need to know how to provide spacing between my textfield and button on the screen

Tags: flutter

So Basically the issue i am facing is I need to provide equal amount of spacing from the left side and the right side of the screen

The code of my file is attached below the code is in flutter

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:flutter/src/widgets/container.dart';
import 'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart';

class PhoneNumberDetails extends StatefulWidget {
  const PhoneNumberDetails({super.key});

  @override
  State<PhoneNumberDetails> createState() => _PhoneNumberDetailsState();
}

class _PhoneNumberDetailsState extends State<PhoneNumberDetails> {
  TextEditingController countryCode = TextEditingController();
  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    countryCode.text = '+91';
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(
          'Verify Number',
          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 20),
        ),
      ),
      body: Container(
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              Image.asset(
                'assets/otpimage.png',
                height: 150,
                width: 150,
              ),
              Text(
                'Phone Verification',
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: 10,
              ),
              Text('Please enter your mobile number to get started'),
              SizedBox(
                height: 25,
              ),
              Container(
                height: 55,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  border: Border.all(width: 1, color: Colors.grey),
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
                ),
                child: Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: [
                    SizedBox(
                      width: 10,
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      width: 40,
                      child: TextField(
                        controller: countryCode,
                        keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                          border: InputBorder.none,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Text(
                      "|",
                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 33, color: Colors.grey),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      width: 10,
                    ),
                    Expanded(
                      child: TextField(
                        keyboardType: TextInputType.phone,
                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                          border: InputBorder.none,
                          hintText: "Phone",
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: 20,
              ),
              SizedBox(
                width: double.infinity,
                height: 45,
                child: ElevatedButton(
                  style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                    backgroundColor: Colors.green.shade600,
                    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                    ),
                  ),
                  child: Text('Send Code'),
                  onPressed: () {
                    Navigator.pushNamed(context, 'verify');
                  },
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Basically i need the output in the following way

The output of this code is:
[image: output of the code]

[image: This should be the expected output]

Comment: Use padding in the horizontal axis

Comment: Atharva Deshpande Add padding to inside `Container` or `SingleChildScrollView`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flutter padding for all widgets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44053363/flutter-padding-for-all-widgets)

Comment: LMAO, everyone hungry for SCORES. Too many duplicate answers but still people adding duplicate answer for such a simple stuff instead of closing the question !!

Answer (score 0):

You can include padding on the scaffold body. while you are using Container widget, you can use padding of it.

```dart
      body: Container(
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(16), //this
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Column(
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your `Row` and `ElevatedButton` inside `Padding`

```
Padding(
    padding: EdgeInsets.only(horizontal:16.0),
    child: Row(...),
  ),
```

```
Padding(
    padding: EdgeInsets.only(horizontal:16.0),
    child:ElevatedButton(...)
 )
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Padding Widget :

```
Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
      child: "YOUR WIDGET",
),
```

Answer (score 0):

Add Padding to Your `Container` or `SingleChildScrollView` like below

```
 Container(
// padding: EdgeInsets.all(16), or use this
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          child: SingleChildScrollView(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(16),
            child: Column(),
    ),
  ),
```

Your Result-> [image]

Answer (score 0):

Simply Wrap your `Row` and `ElevatedButton` inside a `Padding`.